# Insert multiple rows into a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

What I want to do is create a stored procedure that will insert into one table from another table, but the amount of rows being inserted will vary depending on the amount of instances of c_id in the 'basket' table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_Transaction` ()
BEGIN

INSERT INTO transactions 
    (t_id, p_id, u_id, price, qty, total)  status, when_sold) 
VALUES 
    (@t_id, @p_id, @c_id, @Price, @Qty, @total, );
    SELECT p_id, c_id, qty FROM basket;


END
```

I want to insert into the above 'transactions' table from my 'basket' table for every instance of c_id equalling a specified value. So there could be just one or many rows being inserted. t_id will stay constant for each row inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO transactions (t_id, p_id, u_id, price, qty, total)
    SELECT @t_id, p_id, c_id, qty, @total FROM basket;
```